# GNURoot from the android command line or the autostart on power on

Tags: android, linux

It would be great for GNURoot to be an autostart process in Android. I do not want to launch it manually and then set "Launch as Fake Root" and click the button "Launch Rootfs" in the GUI.

To this end, I would like to directly launch GNURoot from the Android command line, instead of launching it from the its start icon,

I tried this,

```
/data/data/champion.gnuroot/app_install/support/wheezy/proot -r /data/data/champion.gnuroot/app_install/roots/wheezy -0 -v -1 -b /dev -b /proc -b /data -b /mnt -b /proc/mounts:/etc/mtab -b /:/host-rootfs -b /tmp-mksh -b /factory -b /logs -b /sdcard -b /preload -b /storage -b /efs -b /config -b /cache -b /acct -b /vendor -b /d -b /system -b /data /bin/bash
```

I got this error,

```
/bin/bash: /system/lib/libc.so.6: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
/bin/bash: /system/lib/libc.so.6: no version information available (required by /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5)
/bin/bash: /system/lib/libc.so.6: no version information available (required by /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2)
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-lookup.c: 169: check_match: Assertion `version->filename == ((void *)0) || ! _dl_name_match_p (version->filename, map)' failed!
```

How can I make the proot command work for roots/wheezy ?

I would also like dropbear (ssh) to run once Wheezy has booted in GNURoot?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the GNURoot-Debian app directly from the android command line 
by running:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.gnuroot.debian/com.gnuroot.debian.GNURootMain
```

You can also directly launch a terminal window using this command:

```
am start -a com.gnuroot.debian.NEW_WINDOW -n com.gnuroot.debian/com.gnuroot.debian.GNURootMain
```

To launch other windows of the GNURoot Debian such as the XWINDOW just append the commands above with the right "action" from the [github app manifest file](https://github.com/corbinlc/GNURootDebian/blob/master/GNURootDebianSource/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)

To auto-start it you can install an an init.d app such like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ryosoftware.initd&hl=en)
and set it to launch a myautorun.sh script that can look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "--- Opening GNURoot Debian Terminal ---"
am start -a com.gnuroot.debian.NEW_WINDOW -n com.gnuroot.debian/com.gnuroot.debian.GNURootMain
```

Hope this helps!